# GPVar condition is not working when parameter is "slugified" in TYPO3 9LTS

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, slug, typo3-9.x

In TypoScript it's possible to use conditions, e.g. to detect if a single view of a news should be shown. This looks like

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
```

or the like. This construct does not work anymore in 9LTS (9.5.7), if the named parameter is "slugified" in the site configuration like

```
News:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Without the given configuration the condition works well.

I expect the GPvar condition will be valid, even the parameter is not in the URL because of the mapping. At least I expect another condition to achieve the detection if a parameter is set, even if it's mapped to a slug/path_segment

Answer (score 2):

Found it: Symfony expressions are working:

`[(request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'])['news'] > 0 || (request.getParsedBody()['tx_news_pi1'])['news'] > 0]`